# JFET Id calculation mismatch in SPICE

Tags: spice, jfet, python

I'm simulating the following circuit in PySpice:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqHk3P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this configuration, the N-JFET is always in saturation mode, as you can see by the plot of `Vds - (Vgs - Vto) = Vds - Vgt`, which is always positive:

[image: Voltage Plots]

Hence, the value of Id should be given by the following equation, according to the S&H model:

$$ I_d = 0.5 \beta (V_{gs} - V_t)^2 (1 + \lambda V_{ds}) $$

However, when I compare the value of the measured `Id = (Vdd - Vd) / Rd` to the one calculated from the formula above, I get the following mismatch:

[image]

Could anybody help me on what I missed here? Below you can find the Python code:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PySpice.Spice.Netlist import Circuit
from prefixed import Float


def main():
    F0 = 20  # [Hz]
    FS = 48000  # [Hz]
    temp_c = 20  # [celsius]
    A = 1.0  # [V] amplitude, linear
    T = 0.1  # [seconds]

    # Spice circuit, based on the LSK189A from LTSpice
    circuit = Circuit('JFET')
    LSK189A = circuit.model("LSK189A", "NJF",
                            Beta="2.2m",
                            Betatce="-0.5",
                            Vto="-1.13",
                            Vtotc="-2.5m",
                            Lambda="4.3m",
                            Is="3f",
                            Xti="0",
                            Isr="0",
                            Alpha="30u",
                            N="1",
                            Rd="11",
                            Rs="30",
                            Cgd="3.19p",
                            Cgs="2.92p",
                            Fc="0.5",
                            Vk="120",
                            M="320m",
                            Pb="0.8",
                            Kf="0.0009f",
                            Af="1",
                            Gdsnoi="2.15",
                            Nlev="1",  # changed from original 3
                            Mfg="Linear_Systems",
                            )
    # component values
    Vdd = 9.0
    Rg = 1E6
    Rd = 4.4E3
    Rs = 1E3

    # Netlist
    circuit.V('Vdd', 'vdd', circuit.gnd, Vdd)
    circuit.SinusoidalVoltageSource(
        'in', 'gate', circuit.gnd, amplitude=A, frequency=F0)
    circuit.R('Rg', 'gate', circuit.gnd, Rg)
    circuit.R('Rd', 'vdd', 'drain', Rd)
    circuit.R('Rs', 'source', circuit.gnd, Rs)
    circuit.J('JFET', 'drain', 'gate', 'source', model="LSK189A")


    jfet_spice_params = {
        p.upper(): LSK189A._parameters[p]
        for p in LSK189A._parameters
    }

    plt.figure()
    plt.title('Id x t')

    # Spice model
    simulator = circuit.simulator(
        temperature=temp_c, nominal_temperature=temp_c)
    # analysis = simulator.dc(Vin=Vsl)
    analysis = simulator.transient(step_time=1/FS, end_time=T)
    y_id_spice = (np.array(analysis["vdd"]) - np.array(analysis["drain"])) / Rd
    y_vgt_spice = np.array(
        analysis["gate"]) - np.array(analysis["source"]) - Float(jfet_spice_params["VTO"])
    y_vds_spice = np.array(analysis["drain"]) - np.array(analysis["source"])
    # if > 0 then saturation
    y_limit_spice = y_vds_spice - y_vgt_spice
    t = np.array(analysis.time)

    plt.plot(t, y_id_spice, label="Id_spice")
    Id_spice_calc = (1 + Float(jfet_spice_params["LAMBDA"]) * y_vds_spice) * 0.5 * Float(
        jfet_spice_params["BETA"]) * y_vgt_spice**2
    plt.plot(t, Id_spice_calc, label="Id_spice_calc")

    plt.xlabel('T [s]')
    plt.ylabel('Id [A]')
    plt.margins(0, 0.1)
    plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')
    plt.legend()

    plt.figure()
    plt.title('V x t')
    plt.plot(t, y_vgt_spice, label=f"Vgt")
    plt.plot(t, y_limit_spice, label=f"Vds-Vgt")
    plt.xlabel('T [s]')
    plt.ylabel('V [V]')
    plt.margins(0, 0.1)
    plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you try messing around with the threshold voltage?

Comment: No I haven't. Vto is a fixed SPICE parameter. I did try with different NJT models though. The mismatch was also there.

Comment: What is `Vgt`?  Did you mean `Vgs`?

Comment: `Vgt = Vgs - Vt`

Comment: OK, gotcha.  Never seen it notated like that.

Comment: Where did you get the `0.5` factor from?

Comment: My reference was the Sedra/Smith Microelectronic Circuits book. There the multiplying factor in the saturation region is defined as `1/2 * kn * W/L`. I assumed that `kn * W/L` was the equivalent of the SPICE's beta

Comment: That's for MOSFETs, hence the `W` and `L`.  My edition of Sedra/Smith (the 5th one) doesn't even cover JFETs.  The JFET equation is defined differently.

Comment: Yes, that is the same one I have. The Shichman and Hodges should apply in a similar way, as the only difference is the silicon dioxide layer at the gate. JFETs also have W and L, right? Another place where I saw it was [this paper](https://sbmicro.org.br/sforum-eventos/sforum2016/05.pdf)

Comment: @edwillys `W` and `L` are only used for MOSFETs...at least in SPICE.  Anyway, I think the problem is if someone says they're using the Shichman-Hodges (or any) model for something (anything), you need to see how they explicitly implement it and define the parameters.  For SPICE it's implemented a certain way, and the transconductance parameter is different between JFETs and MOSFETs.  Besides the textbook mentioned in the answer below and the ngspice manual, you can also take a look at the original SPICE2 thesis for the implementation: https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1975/9602.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 0.5 factor should not be there  in your calculation. See 3-22 page 143 of 2nd edition **Semiconductor Device Modeling With Spice** (Guiseppe et al.) which is the same equation as you have but the 0.5 has been rolled into \$\beta\$.

The remaining discrepancy in the static model is mostly accounted for by Rs (30Ω in the 'A' bin model), which reduces Vgs.

I presume the 'B' model is intended to be closer to typical with 'A' and 'C' representing outliers..

Comment: Hmmm...I noticed the same thing as you, but there still remains a discrepancy.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HhU4.png

Comment: @SteKulov That's strange, something else is going on.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now.  I had to dissect the Python code to figure it out.  He's using the Vds and the Vgs values calculated via the SPICE engine where Beta=2.2m, but then he's using those values along with the wrong Beta=1.1m to calculate Ids.  Changing the Python code to remove the `*0.5` factor and make `Rs=0` is confirmed to have the plots line right on top of each other.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWlNX.png

Comment: Thanks for having a deep look in the code @SteKulov. Spehro: Very nice catch with the internal Rs value affecting Vgs. Similarly, I assume, one should need to set Rd to 0 ohms in order to account for the discrepancy in Vds, which plays a role in the channel length modulation. Unfortunately I don't have access to this book. Could you please clarify what the A, B and C models are? Also, I assume that if the 0.5 factor is not present in the saturation formula for Id, a factor of 2 should be accounted for in the triode region, correct?

Comment: I don't *know* what the A B C are, I just see that they're available models at the manufacturer and don't line up with any known designations on the parts. There is a very wide range of possible Idss and if you look at the Idss for each of the models you get 2.6mA, 5.6mA, 10.8mA respectively. Datasheet limits for Idss are 2.5mA and 15mA with 5mA typical, so the B model is closest to typical. Rd doesn't make nearly as much difference as Rs because it doesn't affect Vgs.

Comment: @edwillys  If you don't have access to the book you can take a look at Equation 9.5 in Section 9.2.2 of the ngspice manual:  https://ngspice.sourceforge.io/docs.html

Comment: Thanks @SteKulov!

Comment: @edwillys Also, you may be able to directly access [Semiconductor Device Modeling With Spice, 2nd ed.](https://archive.org/details/semiconductordev0000mass/mode/2up?view=theater&ui=embed&wrapper=false).